# Change font-weight of an asp:RadioButton Text in client script

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 `asp:RadioButton` that are unchecked when the page is loaded. When one is checked, I want to change the `font-weight` to bold in client script. I tried:

```
radio1.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the the css class using the attributes property. I am assuming radio1 is the id if so you could modify your c# code to

```
radio1.Attributes["class"] = "newCssClassName";
```

I personally have never modified a single property of css using c#. To do that I have always used something like jQuery.

Try to create a new css class such as

```
.rbSelected
{
font-weight:bold;
{
```

And then toggle them accordingly ( your css property should be font-weight not fontWeight)

Also a word of warning with controls such as radio buttons and checkboxes the browser will override your styling in most cases. Each browser will render the control differently regardless of what style(s) you apply. If you are looking for something custom you may need to create your own control/element (Such as an image/element that looks like a checkbox but has manages states handled in code)

Answer (score 0):

For bold

```
$("#YourElementID").css("font-weight","bolder");
```

For regular

```
$("#YourElementID").css("font-weight","normal");
```

You can create a function with this lines to toggle the `font-weight`. To call the `javascript function` from the server side controls use:

```
radio.Attributes.Add("onclick","functionname()");
```

This will add the functionname to the `onclick event` when the `radio button` is rendered to the browser.

Comment: good point however the OP did not specify using jQuery it looks as if they are attempting to manage this through c# code-behind. I agree though with your approach if jQuery is the preferred solution.